# ListView onClick works in emulator but not on touch phone

Tags: android

can anyone tell me why this does not work on my LG400f touch phone but works fine with a mouse click in the emulator?

**Code**

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listContactsList);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_contacts,  R.id.listContactsView, values);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
listView.setClickable(true);
listView.setFocusable(true);
listView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Object selection = (Object) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selection.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // Toast is triggered with mouse click in emulator but not touch in phone
```

**XML**

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listContactsList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    tools:context=".ListContacts" />
```

Comment: Try changing the line listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() to "listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){}"

Comment: So on the device, `selection` is `null` or is `onItemClick` not run?

Comment: Cant get this listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){} to work Jade

Comment: Sam, I modified the code to display a Toast to simplify and Toast does not display on touch

Comment: Have you tried using onItemClickListener instead of onItemClick

Comment: Irish, yes I have with no joy. I get this in DDMS whilst running on phone: KeyCharacterMap Can't open keycharmap file

Comment: Post `list_contacts.xml`. Also when you reply to a specific user use `@Sam` otherwise we might not know that you responded.

Comment: Remove `setClickable`. The *items* are supposed to be clickable, not the ListView itself. When the ListView is clickable it consumes the click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to the people who responded to this question.

I have not exactly re-solved this issue directly but have coded a variation that works.

Firstly my previous class was defined like so: **ListContacts extends Activity** and the code was as I displayed it in the original question.

I now have defined my class **ListContacts extends ListActivity** and changed the code (which works) like this:

First delete setContentView(R.layout.xxxx) from onCreate() and the textview in the XML file.

**Code:**

```
this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values));
ListView listView = getListView();
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Object selection = (Object) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selection.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

On the Listview in the xml check the touchscreenBlocksFocus = true

Comment: I've *never* had to use `touchscreenBlocksFocus` in any standard case, there must be a simpler solution. Also, please focus on *recent* questions that have not had an accepted answer for 5+ years. Thanks!